# Can't Use on_stats Option Using Laravel HTTP Client

Tags: php, laravel

Currently, I'm using [Laravel HTTP client](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-clien) to make a request to an external URL. Mostly, the package working fine until I try to implement `on_stats` option from Guzzle.

From [the doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client), it says we can use Guzzle options using `withMethod()` method.

Here is my sample code to implement `on_stats` option using HTTP client.

```php
$response = Http::withOptions([
    'debug' => true,
    'on_stats' => function(\GuzzleHttp\TransferStats $stats) {
        Log::debug($stats->getTransferTime());
    }
])
->get('https://laravel.com');

dd($response->status());
```

The code above will produce an error with the message:

```
Second array member is not a valid method
```

However, when I'm using the option within the Guzzle package directly, it works fine.

```php
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
$response = $client->get('https://laravel.com', [
    'on_stats' => function(\GuzzleHttp\TransferStats $stats) {
        Log::debug($stats->getTransferTime());
    }
]);

dd((string) $response->getStatusCode());
```

Any idea why this is happening? Is it a bug from the HTTP client wrapper from Laravel?
FYI, I'm using Laravel 8.x.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`withOptions` uses this code:

```
return tap($this, function ($request) use ($options) {
            return $this->options = array_merge_recursive($this->options, $options);
        });
```

So I'm guessing passing a closure in may not work, since it's not actually an array. From https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/httpwithtoken-get-total-time-of-request , you can get it from the response instead, so try this:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client;
$response = $client->get('https://laravel.com');

Log::debug($response->transferStats->getTransferTime());
```

Comment: What if we're tracking redirects and need stats for every request?